# Given three vectors, how to find an orthonormal basis closest to them?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

I know Gram-Schmidt process but that is not what I am looking for. Given three vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$, I want to find three vectors $\{w_1,w_2,w_3\} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ such that
$$(w_i,w_j) = \delta_{ij}, \quad \forall i,j\in\{1,2,3\},$$
$$D=\sum_{j=1}^3 \|v_j-w_j\|^2\ \mbox{is minimal.}$$
The drawback of the GS process is that it assumes a preferred order in the 3-tuple and only changes the length of the first vector, resulting in the change being done to the second and third too large and the distance $D$ suboptimal. I want to deform all three in a "fair" manner.

Comment: This question may not be well posed. Vectors $v_i$ can be of any length and even linearly dependent, which makes the minimal not unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the norm is the Euclidean $2$-norm, the problem has been studied to death. Put it simply, since $\|x\|^2=x^Tx=\operatorname{trace}(xx^T)$, you can rewrite $D$ as a constant plus $-2\operatorname{trace}(VW^T)$. By performing singular value decomposition on $V$, the answer is trivial (but a little care has to be taken if $W$ is not just an orthogonal matrix but a rotation matrix).

Comment: I can see all the steps up to the trace and indeed that's how far I reached myself prior to asking. Could you please shed some more light on how the SVD helps from there on?

Comment: @VašekPotoček Let $V=Q_1SQ_2^T$ be a SVD. Then $-\mathrm{tr}(VW^T)=-\mathrm{tr}(Q_1SQ_2^TW^T)=-\mathrm{tr}(SQ_2^TW^TQ_1)$. Hence this negative trace is minimised when $Q_2^TW^TQ_1=I$, i.e. when $W=Q_1Q_2^T$.

Comment: That's excellent, thanks!

Comment: I'm wondering, what if we have a set of V matrices: $\{V_i | i=1,2,...,k\}$, and to find ONE mat W which is closest to the V set? Then $D=\sum_{i=1}^k\|V_i-W\|_F$, how to minimize this $D$?

Comment: @zhangxaochen I don't know, but you definitely need a numerical package.

Comment: @user1551 I don't know why you mentioned "numerical package" while I'm consulting the math theory?

Answer (score 2):

I've the same question. After googling keywords *"nearest orthogonal matrix"*, I found this post, and two other related posts:

[1]. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix#Nearest_orthogonal_matrix

[2]. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Applications_of_the_SVD

> Nearest orthogonal matrix
>
> It is possible to use the SVD of a
> square matrix A to determine the orthogonal matrix O closest to A. The
> closeness of fit is measured by the Frobenius norm of O − A. The
> solution is the product UV∗.[3] This intuitively makes sense because
> an orthogonal matrix would have the decomposition UIV∗ where I is the
> identity matrix, so that if A = UΣV∗ then the product A = UV∗ amounts
> to replacing the singular values with ones.

The $D=\sum_{j=1}^3 \|v_j-w_j\|^2$ is the Frobenius norm of **(V-W)**.

Hope this would help ;)